# Getting additional e_id even after joining conditions are satisfied in SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
    e_id       NUMBER(10),
    sys_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    ref_id     NUMBER(10),
    sys_other  VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(805,'SRC',NULL,'Email');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(805,'SRC',NULL,'Test');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(805,'TGT',NULL,null);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(805,'TGT',128,'Email');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(6122,'SRC',NULL,'Email');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(6122,'TGT',NULL,'Email');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(122,'SRC',128,null);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES(122,'TGT',128,null);

COMMIT;
```

Database version: Oracle 18c.

I want to create one report wherein I need to include only those `e_id` whose `ref_id` is not null and `sys_other` is either `Email or null`. Other than this combination, that `e_id` will not be considered in the report. For ex:

`e_id = 122` it should come in report as `ref_id` is not null and `sys_other` is null

`e_id = 6122` it should not come in report as `ref_id` is null

`e_id = 805` it should also not come in report where `ref_id` is not null but in `sys_other` we have value other than `Email and null` which is `Test` so we should exclude this e_id

Logic:
Basically, need to check two columns ref_id and sys_other. If ref_id is null then we should exclude those e_id and if it is not null then need to check sys_other column and if it has 'Email' than include otherwise exclude irrespective of column sys_name

My Attempt:

```
SELECT e_id,ref_id,sys_other
FROM test_tab
WHERE ref_id IS NOT NULL
  AND (sys_other = 'Email' OR sys_other IS NULL)
GROUP BY e_id,ref_id,sys_other;
```

But the above query is giving me 805 id which should be excluded.

Expected output:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
| E_ID | REF_ID | SYS_OTHER |
+------+--------+-----------+
|  122 |    128 | null      |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: (805,'TGT',128,'Email') will get through

Comment: I'd expect id = 805  to pass "ref_id is not null _and_ sys_other is either Email or null"

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes but per e_id I need to check
1. Ref_id column whether this is null or not
2. Then sys_other column if it contains only 'Email' or not

Comment: @jarlh Yes but I need to exclude those e_id in which it has other than 'Email'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       MAX(ref_id)    AS ref_id,
       MAX(sys_other) AS sys_other
FROM   test_tab
GROUP BY e_id
HAVING COUNT(ref_id) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN sys_other <> 'Email' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Which will group by each `e_id` and for each group:

- count the non-null `ref_id` and ensure that there is as least 1 row and
- count the non-null `sya_other` values that are not `Email` and ensure that there are no rows that are non-null, non-email rows in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the e_id acording to conditions stated in Logic:

```sql
WITH
    exclude AS
        (
            SELECT
                E_ID,
                SYS_OTHER
            FROM
                TEST_TAB
            WHERE
                SYS_OTHER Is Not Null And SYS_OTHER <> 'Email'
            GROUP BY
                E_ID,
                SYS_OTHER
        )

SELECT 
    e_id,
    ref_id,
    sys_other
FROM 
    test_tab
WHERE 
    E_ID Not IN(SELECT E_ID FROM exclude) And
    ref_id IS NOT NULL AND 
    Nvl(sys_other, 'Email') = 'Email'
GROUP BY 
    e_id,
    ref_id,
    sys_other;
```